# Displaying table using HTML

Tags: html, json, html-table

I want to display the below contents in table format using HTML.
Can you please quickly help to display this content using HTML.
please find below sample table contents.

```
Name | Count
------------
X1   | 6
X2   | 3
```

Comment: It's basic! Please learn the basic before asking. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: i mean to ask in this way "instead of hardcoding the values in the HTML table, directly from another data file how can i display that data in the table

Comment: `another data file` what is the data file? Like **json** file?

Comment: yes,how can we use json file data into the row present in a html table

Comment: "can you `quickly` help?" . No!

Answer (score 0):

Read the code and if you don't understand anything, feel free to ask.

Just a note.. You can append each row and cell with `.appendChild` or something. The reason I did it by build a string and append it in the end is that DOM manipulation is heavy, so I prefer to do it once but not for each row and cell.. Got it?

```js
var jsonResponse = '[ { "name": "x16", "count": "x23" } ]';
var json = JSON.parse(jsonResponse);

var output = '';
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    output += '<tr><td>' + json[i].name + '</td><td>' + json[i].count + '</td></tr>';
}

document.querySelector('tbody').innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Count</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: how to achieve this functionality using javascript file?

Comment: what do you mean by `javascript file`? Do you mean that the `jsonResponse` located in another javascript file? If so, it doesn't need to change. It should works anyway. If not, explain to me please..

Comment: instead of using Json,with javascript code itself  how can I achieve this?like using of javascript code as an external script and using that  external script in a table to display the data in the browser?